# How to show button on selection of a value from the angular material select dropdown

Tags: select, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-6

Once i select a dropdown value from a dropdown field i want a section in another div to be loaded 
ngif would help me do this, but how could i add this as a condition for the display of that section 
Any dropdown selected should open that section 
Later would customise it to different other sections in a div to load based on selection of the different dropdowns values accordingly

Comment: you mean like:
option1 would show div1
option2 would show div2

then later you need to add option3 that should show div3?

Comment: @jsnewbie yes that way, like in my drop down i have options like -> individual -> business, i get a div1 when i select individual, and div2 when i select business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solve by using selectionchange event emmiter function, whenever you select a value from the dropdown you can call an eventemmiter function. See the code below:

Html Code:

```
<div>
    <mat-select placeholder="Options" 
    (selectionChange)="onSelecetionChange($event.value)">
        <mat-option value="individual ">Individual </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="business">Business</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="individual">
   Individual Div
</div>
<div *ngIf="business">
   Business Div
</div>
```

My ts code:

```
individual: boolean;
business: boolean;

onSelecetionChange( value: string ) {
if( value === 'individual') {
  // You can add some service call or customize your data from here
  this.individual = true;
}
if( value === 'business') {
  // You can add some service call or customize your data from here
  this.business = true;
}
```

}